# Add MouseOut in jQuery Code

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I'm trying to make a div jQuery code to show a div after mouse over on another div!

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pic').mouseover(function() {
        $('.rank').fadeOut(200);        
        $(this).next('.rank').fadeIn(400);   
    });

    $("div.rank").hide();
});​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pic">Mouse Over</div>
<div class="rank">Show Somthing</div>​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CaMwL/

Now, problem is, i need to add mouseout event to this code, i want to make a div hide when i move the mouse out! and i dont know how i can do that!

Comment: FYI, [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) makes binding to both easier. `$('...').hover(function(){ /* mouse over */ },function(){ /* mouse out */ });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/633hD/1/

You can chain the API: `.mouseout` http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.rank").hide();

    $('.pic').mouseover(function() {
        $('.rank').fadeOut(200);        
        $(this).next('.rank').fadeIn(400);   
    }).mouseout(function() {
           $("div.rank").hide();
    });
});​
```

Comment: i cant check and accept all answers, but thank u dear for helping me.

Comment: @Alireza No problems, `:))` Glad it helped you!

Answer (score 2):

do you mean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pic').hover(
        function() {
            $('.rank').fadeOut(200);        
            $(this).next('.rank').fadeIn(400);   
        },
        function() {
            $('.rank').fadeIn(400);        
            $(this).next('.rank').fadeOut(200);   
        });

    $("div.rank").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.pic').mouseout(function() {
    $("div.rank").hide();
});   
});
```

Also, you could add onmouseover and onmouseout attributes to the div element, and set the value to a javascript function with jquery.

Comment: i cant check and accept all answers, but thank u dear for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('.pic').mouseout(function() {
    $("div.rank").hide();
});
```

find jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/CaMwL/5/

Comment: i cant check and accept all answers, but thank u dear for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pic').mouseover(function() {
        $('.rank').fadeOut(200);        
        $(this).next('.rank').fadeIn(400);   
    });

     $('.pic').mouseout(function() {

         $("div.rank").hide();   
    });


});
```

Comment: i cant check and accept all answers, but thank u dear for helping me.